# If statement only producing one output for all conditions

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have multiple aggregated function done with a decorator in python.

These `if` conditions are only producing output for one condition on different values.

I have tried changing the positions but they always produce the same output.

What am I doing wrong?

How can I make the values different as per my requirements in the conditions

Sample code:

```
   # This class allows function addition, multiplication, division 
            etc.
class operable:
   def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
   def __call__(self, x):
        return self.f(x)

def op_to_function_op(op):
   def function_op(self, operand):
        def f(x):
            return op(self(x), operand(x))
        return operable(f)
   return function_op

 for name, op in [(name, getattr(operator, name)) for name in 
    dir(operator) if "__" in name]:
    try:
        op(1,2)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    else:
        setattr(operable, name, op_to_function_op(op))

 def allocate_service(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    platinum_customers = []
    silver_customers = []
    gold_customers = []
    non_customers = []
    message = ''


    for customer in queryset:



        @operable
        def getAge():
            age = 0

            if customer.Age == Customer.objects.get(Age = "60 +"):
                age = 0

            elif customer.Age == Customer.objects.get(Age = "36 - 59"):
                age = 1
            else:
                age = 2


        def getEducation():
            education = 0
            if customer.Education == Customer.objects.get(Education = 
                "Highschool and below"):
                education = 0
            else:
                education = 1


        def getEmployment():
            employment = 0
            if customer.Employment == Customer.objects.get(Employment = 
                "Student"):
                employment = 0
            elif customer.Employment == Customer.objects.get(Employment = 
                "Contract"):
                employment = 1
            else:
                employment = 2


        def getStability():
            stability = 0
            if customer.Employer_Stability == 
              Customer.objects.get(Employer_Stability = "Unstable"):
                stability = 0
            else:
                stability = 1


        def getResidential():
            residential = 0
            if customer.Residential_Status == 
                Customer.objects.get(Residential_Status = "Rented"):
                residential = 0
            else:
                residential = 1


        def getSalary():
            salary = 0
            if customer.Salary == Customer.objects.get(Salary <= 1000):
                salary = 0
            elif customer.Salary == Customer.objects.get(Salary <= 10001 and 
                Salary > 1000):
                salary = 1
            else:
                salary = 2


        def getLoyalty():
            loyalty = 0
            loy = Customer.objects.get(Customer_Loyalty <= 2)

            if customer.Customer_Loyalty == loy.Customer_Loyalty:
                loyalty = 0
            else:
                loyalty = 1


        def getBalance():
            balance = 0
            if customer.Balance == Customer.objects.get(Balance <= 2500):
                balance = 0
            elif customer.Balance == Customer.objects.get(Balance <= 10001 
                and Balance > 2500):
                balance = 1
            else:
                balance = 2



        def feat_list():
            total = getAge + getEducation + getEmployment + getStability + 
                getResidential + getSalary + getLoyalty + getBalance
            return total



        if feat_list() <= 11:
            customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 
                'Silver Package')
            silver_customers.append(customer.Name)

        elif 11 < feat_list() <= 15:
            customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 
                'Gold Package')
            gold_customers.append(customer.Name)
        elif feat_list() > 15:
            customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 
                "Platinum Package")
            platinum_customers.append(customer.Name)
        else:
            customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = "No 
                Service Package")
            non_customers.append(customer.name)

        customer.save()

        if platinum_customers:
            message = 'The following customers are now Platinum Customers: 
                {}'.format(', '.join(platinum_customers))
        if silver_customers:
            message = 'The following customers are now Silver Customers: 
                {}'.format(', '.join(silver_customers))
        if gold_customers:
            message = 'The following customers are now Gold Customers: 
                {}'.format(', '.join(gold_customers))
        if not platinum_customers and not silver_customers and not          
               gold_customers:
             message = 'No customer changes made!'
        ModelAdmin.message_user(request, message, level=SUCCESS)
    allocate_service.short_description = 'Allocate Service'
```

I would like to run this section of the code in order to determine the value of `Service Level`:

```
    if feat_list() <= 11:
        customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 'Silver Package')
        silver_customers.append(customer.Name)

    elif 11 < feat_list() <= 15:
        customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 'Gold Package')
        gold_customers.append(customer.Name)
    elif feat_list() > 15:
        customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = "Platinum Package")
        platinum_customers.append(customer.Name)
    else:
        customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = "No Service Package")
        non_customers.append(customer.name)

    customer.save()
```

The problem is that it is giving a `Service Level` of `Silver Packages` to every query set even if I had custom edited some to get `Platinum or Gold Packages`. I am not sure what exactly is wrong with this block as. it is running though providing a undesired output

Comment: Your code contains lots of `if`s; we have no idea which specific ones you're having trouble with.  Try editing your question to include an example of __running__ the code, along with output that illustrates the problem.

Comment: ok, let me do that

Comment: Also, its unclear if you have inner functions defined in the parent function, etc. The indentation needs another look

Comment: Shouldn't `total = getAge + getEducation + getEmployment + getStability + getResidential + getSalary + getLoyalty + getBalance` have **()** after each *get*?

Comment: I have updated with correct indentation. @KenY-N I tried adding the **()** and I am getting the error `TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: It doesn't make any sense at all to define classes inside for loops

Comment: @e4c5 I added the `class operable:` so that I could be able to add my get functions directly in the `feat_list()` functions

Comment: That statement doesn't make any sense either. This is very poor code layout. Classes should be defined at the top of your file. If a class is not reusable why make one anyway??

Comment: thanks for that feedback, I am still learning some of these things.

Comment: I cannot find any information on `@operable`, but I found [this page](https://turion.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/add-and-multiply-python-functions-operable-functions/). What is the type of `total`? Should all the *get* functions be `@operable`? Should you `return total()`?

Comment: yes, I think all should be operable thought it seems to not make a difference. Total is return type as `<type 'instance'>`

Comment: you must print the total parameter.  I think it is probably 0 or undefined.

Comment: it seems so. I am not sure where I did wrong @TalAvissar

Comment: also you need to return the value from each operation @maffsojah

Comment: The functions are returning `instance` objects not `integers` as I require. Is there a way to convert

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should use your decorator on each function because otherwise you are only evaluating the get age as operable.

1. You need to add the decorator to each function you are evaluating
2. You need to **return** the result from each sub-operation (so you can sum it with feat_list() )

and that is why you receive a score which is below 11 so you end up with silver_customers. 
It is important to print the total variable so it is easy to track the result:

```
  # This class allows function addition, multiplication, division 
            etc.
class operable:
   def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
   def __call__(self, x):
        return self.f(x)

def op_to_function_op(op):
   def function_op(self, operand):
        def f(x):
            return op(self(x), operand(x))
        return operable(f)
   return function_op

 for name, op in [(name, getattr(operator, name)) for name in 
    dir(operator) if "__" in name]:
    try:
        op(1,2)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    else:
        setattr(operable, name, op_to_function_op(op))

 def allocate_service(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    platinum_customers = []
    silver_customers = []
    gold_customers = []
    non_customers = []
    message = ''


    for customer in queryset:

        @operable
        def getAge():
            age = 0

            if customer.Age == Customer.objects.get(Age = "60 +"):
                age = 0

            elif customer.Age == Customer.objects.get(Age = "36 - 59"):
                age = 1
            else:
                age = 2
            return age

        @operable
        def getEducation():
            education = 0
            if customer.Education == Customer.objects.get(Education = 
                "Highschool and below"):
                education = 0
            else:
                education = 1
            return education
        @operable
        def getEmployment():
            employment = 0
            if customer.Employment == Customer.objects.get(Employment = 
                "Student"):
                employment = 0
            elif customer.Employment == Customer.objects.get(Employment = 
                "Contract"):
                employment = 1
            else:
                employment = 2
            return employment

        @operable
        def getStability():
            stability = 0
            if customer.Employer_Stability == 
              Customer.objects.get(Employer_Stability = "Unstable"):
                stability = 0
            else:
                stability = 1
            return stability 

        @operable
        def getResidential():
            residential = 0
            if customer.Residential_Status == 
                Customer.objects.get(Residential_Status = "Rented"):
                residential = 0
            else:
                residential = 1
            return residential 

        @operable
        def getSalary():
            salary = 0
            if customer.Salary == Customer.objects.get(Salary <= 1000):
                salary = 0
            elif customer.Salary == Customer.objects.get(Salary <= 10001 and 
                Salary > 1000):
                salary = 1
            else:
                salary = 2
            return salary
        @operable
        def getLoyalty():
            loyalty = 0
            loy = Customer.objects.get(Customer_Loyalty <= 2)

            if customer.Customer_Loyalty == loy.Customer_Loyalty:
                loyalty = 0
            else:
                loyalty = 1
            return loyalty 
        @operable
        def getBalance():
            balance = 0
            if customer.Balance == Customer.objects.get(Balance <= 2500):
                balance = 0
            elif customer.Balance == Customer.objects.get(Balance <= 10001 
                and Balance > 2500):
                balance = 1
            else:
                balance = 2
            return balance


        def feat_list():
            total = getAge + getEducation + getEmployment + getStability + 
                getResidential + getSalary + getLoyalty + getBalance
            print('total:' + total)
            return total



        if feat_list() <= 11:
            customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 
                'Silver Package')
            silver_customers.append(customer.Name)

        elif 11 < feat_list() <= 15:
            customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 
                'Gold Package')
            gold_customers.append(customer.Name)
        elif feat_list() > 15:
            customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = 
                "Platinum Package")
            platinum_customers.append(customer.Name)
        else:
            customer.Service_Level = Service.objects.get(service_name = "No 
                Service Package")
            non_customers.append(customer.name)

        customer.save()

        if platinum_customers:
            message = 'The following customers are now Platinum Customers: 
                {}'.format(', '.join(platinum_customers))
        if silver_customers:
            message = 'The following customers are now Silver Customers: 
                {}'.format(', '.join(silver_customers))
        if gold_customers:
            message = 'The following customers are now Gold Customers: 
                {}'.format(', '.join(gold_customers))
        if not platinum_customers and not silver_customers and not          
               gold_customers:
             message = 'No customer changes made!'
        ModelAdmin.message_user(request, message, level=SUCCESS)
    allocate_service.short_description = 'Allocate Service'
```

Comment: it is till producing the same output